# Logout removing token but token still stored in service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, header, logout

I have a logout method which removes the token from storage. However in my service the old token is still stored. Therefor when sending HTTP requests it is coming up as the old user. The problem seems to be in the service getting the token. The get token function stores the token and it is never updated on a user logging in

add.service

```
export class AddService {

  token = this.storage.get('token').then(res => {
    this.token = res;
  });

sendComment(comment, patientID) {
    headers = headers.delete('Authorization', '');

    // this is old token;
    console.log(this.token);

    console.log(this.storage.get('token'));
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', '' + this.token);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('comment', comment);
    formData.append('patientID', patientID);
    return this.http.post<any>(apiUrl + 'addComment.php', formData, {headers});
  }

}
```

logout.ts

```
logout() {
    console.log('Old token');
    console.log(this.token);
    this.storage.clear().then (val => {
      console.log(val);
      console.log('Empty');
    });
    this.gettoken();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }
```

Comment: try to use storage without callback. `this.storage.clear()` simple like this.

Comment: Nope still not working.

Comment: also clear your `this.token = '';` in logout function

Comment: But i need to set the token in this function. I dont thing the storage is the problem. It seems to be this token = this.storage.get('token').then(res => {
    this.token = res;
  }); in the service

Comment: sorry. i edited my comment. you should clear your token variable in logout function.

Comment: Hi the token is being cleared fine and when i login in my service i can get the new token. The problem is assigning it to the this.token as it always seems to be the first token?